# Rest api is not working from angular but its fine when call from post man

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

when I add @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')") in my controller and call from angular its not working but its fine when call from post man.

```
@GetMapping("/getAllOrgniz")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')")
public ResponseEntity<?> allOrganization () {
    return organizationService.getAllOrganization();
}
```

From Angular:

```
getAllOrganizationList ():void {
    this.organaigationService.getAll().subscribe(data=>{
        this.organizations = data;
    });
 }
```

OrganizationService:

```
public getAll() {
     return this.httpService.getWithToken(this.getAllUrl);
}
```

HttpService:

```
getWithToken (url:any): Observable<any> {
    let token = this.tokenStoreService.getToken();
    console.log(token);
    return this.http.get<any>(this.URL+url,this.httpBearerHeader);
}
```

Spring boot console shows like

> this:com.crm.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt   : Unauthorized error:
>   Full authentication is required to access this resource

Angular log:

> core.js:6014 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status:
>   401, statusText: "OK", url:
>   "http://localhost:8085/api/organization/getAllOrgniz", ok:
>   false, …}headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate:
>   null, lazyInit: ƒ}status: 401statusText: "OK"url:
>   "http://localhost:8085/api/organization/getAllOrgniz"ok: falsename:
>   "HttpErrorResponse"message: "Http failure response for
>   http://localhost:8085/api/organization/getAllOrgniz: 401 OK"error:
>   {timestamp: "2020-06-08T10:14:19.917+00:00", status: 401, error:
>   "Unauthorized", trace:
>   "org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedEx…va:61)↵   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)↵", message: "Error:
>   Unauthorized", …

Comment: Compare the requests sent by Angular and Postman, what are the differences? Are there any errors logged in the browser's console?

Comment: added angular log

Comment: Question number one: _"Compare the requests sent by Angular and Postman, what are the differences?"_. Also, what's `this.httpBearerHeader`?

Comment: httpBearerHeader = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': 'Bearer' + this.tokenStoreService.getToken()

        })
    };

Comment: your API call using Angular is not authenticated, try send your credentials along with your request

Comment: from post man same Bearer token works fine. But from angular it is not working

Comment: For the third time, please: compare the requests sent by Angular and Postman, what are the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the space after 'Bearer' and it should work:

```
httpBearerHeader = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.tokenStoreService.getToken() }) }
```

Comment: @Nahid happy coding :)